# Rails 4 nested form with double association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have an Order model like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_address, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :billing_address, class_name: 'Address'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_address, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, allow_destroy: true
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I am struggling to make a nested form work to allow me to add both addresses in the same form. The params section of the Order is like this:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:contract_id, :billing_address_id, :service_address_id, :valid_from, :valid_to, :contact_person_id, :billing_mode,
                                service_address: [:city_id, :street_id, :number, :block, :entrance, :floor, :apartment, :_destroy],
                                billing_address: [:city_id, :street_id, :number, :block, :entrance, :floor, :apartment, :_destroy])
```

My create action is like this:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@order.service_address = Address.new(params[:order][:service_address])
@order.billing_address = Address.new(params[:order][:billing_address])
```

When submitting this way, the form does not validate, all fields for billing_address being highlighted as incomplete.

If I use `service_address_params` and `billing_adress_params` I get an error of `undefined local variable or method 'service_address_params'`

I am stuck here for two days, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: `new`

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @order.service_address = Address.new
  @order.billing_address = Address.new
end
```

EDIT: `form`

```
<%= simple_form_for @order, data: {validate: 'parsley'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :contract_id, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @contract_id } %>
  <%= f.input :same_billing_address, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 0 } %>

  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= render :partial => 'order_data', :locals => { f: f } %>
  <%= render :partial => 'service_address' %>
  <%= render :partial => 'billing_address' %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

One of the partials for addresses:

```
<%= simple_fields_for :service_address do |sa| %>
  <div class="form-inputs" id="inputs-step2">
    <%= sa.input :city_id, label: 'Oras', collection: @cities, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block2", :required => true, id: 'service_address_city_id' } %>
    <%= sa.input :street_id, label: 'Strada', collection: @streets, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block2", :required => true, id: 'service_address_street_id' } %>
    <%= sa.input :number, label: 'Numar', input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block2", :required => true } %>
    <%= sa.input :block, label: 'Bloc' %>
    <%= sa.input :entrance, label: 'Scara' %>
    <%= sa.input :floor, label: 'Etaj' %>
    <%= sa.input :apartment, label: 'Apartament' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Billing address partial:

```
<%= simple_fields_for :billing_address do |ba| %>
  <div class="form-inputs" id="inputs-step3">
    <%= ba.input :city_id, label: 'Oras', collection: @cities, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block3", :required => true, id: 'billing_address_city_id' } %>
    <%= ba.input :street_id, label: 'Strada', collection: @streets, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block3", :required => true, id: 'billing_address_street_id' } %>
    <%= ba.input :number, label: 'Numar', input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block3", :required => true } %>
    <%= ba.input :block, label: 'Bloc' %>
    <%= ba.input :entrance, label: 'Scara' %>
    <%= ba.input :floor, label: 'Etaj' %>
    <%= ba.input :apartment, label: 'Apartament' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The params hash:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: nZvowtR+Iwo/Rt420w55ZSzNtiZCrjga57dSimDPdg0=
order: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  contract_id: ''
  same_billing_address: '0'
  valid_from: '2013-08-04'
  months: '12'
  billing_mode: '1'
service_address: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  city_id: '1'
  street_id: '19'
  number: '1'
  block: '1'
  entrance: '1'
  floor: '1'
  apartment: '1'
billing_address: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  city_id: '1'
  street_id: '19'
  number: '2'
  block: '2'
  entrance: '2'
  floor: '2'
  apartment: '2'
commit: Create Order
action: create
controller: orders
```

Comment: Can you post your `new` method of your controller? And also the `form code`

Comment: there are no validations inside address model.

Comment: I left them out. There are only for city_id and street.

Comment: Please post your `billing_address` partial too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with a `belongs_to` is a **pain** and quite **tricky** as well.And secondly there are lot of mistakes in the code.I will be explaining one by one.

**Mistake #1**

Your `new` method should be like this

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @order.build_service_address 
  @order.build_billing_address
end
```

In your `create` method,you don't need these lines,remove them.

```
@order.service_address = Address.new(params[:order][:service_address])
@order.billing_address = Address.new(params[:order][:billing_address])
```

**Mistake #2**

Your `order_params` method should be like this

```
def order_params
 params.require(:order).permit(:contract_id, :billing_address_id, :service_address_id,    :valid_from, :valid_to, :contact_person_id, :billing_mode,service_address_attributes: [:city_id, :street_id, :number, :block, :entrance, :floor, :apartment, :_destroy],billing_address_attributes: [:city_id, :street_id, :number, :block, :entrance, :floor, :apartment, :_destroy])
end
```

Notice the changes `service_address_attributes` and `billing_address_attributes`

**Mistake #3**

You are not passing `locals` to your `service_address` and `billing_address` partials.

These lines

```
<%= render :partial => 'service_address' %>
<%= render :partial => 'billing_address' %>
```

should be like this

```
<%= render :partial => 'service_address',:locals => { f: sa }%>
<%= render :partial => 'billing_address',:locals => { f: ba } %>
```

**Update**

Try calling the `partials` like this in the `main form`

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :service_address do |sa| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'service_address',:locals => { f: sa }%>
<% end %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :billing_address do |ba| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'billing_address',:locals => { f: ba } %>
<% end %>
```

And change the code in your `service_address` and `billing_address` `partials` like this

```
#_service_address.html.erb
<div class="form-inputs" id="inputs-step2">
    <%= f.input :city_id, label: 'Oras', collection: @cities, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block2", :required => true, id: 'service_address_city_id' } %>
    <%= f.input :street_id, label: 'Strada', collection: @streets, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block2", :required => true, id: 'service_address_street_id' } %>
    <%= f.input :number, label: 'Numar', input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block2", :required => true } %>
    <%= f.input :block, label: 'Bloc' %>
    <%= f.input :entrance, label: 'Scara' %>
    <%= f.input :floor, label: 'Etaj' %>
    <%= f.input :apartment, label: 'Apartament' %>
  </div>

#_billing_address.html.erb
<div class="form-inputs" id="inputs-step3">
    <%= f.input :city_id, label: 'Oras', collection: @cities, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block3", :required => true, id: 'billing_address_city_id' } %>
    <%= f.input :street_id, label: 'Strada', collection: @streets, input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block3", :required => true, id: 'billing_address_street_id' } %>
    <%= f.input :number, label: 'Numar', input_html: { 'data-parsley-group' => "block3", :required => true } %>
    <%= f.input :block, label: 'Bloc' %>
    <%= f.input :entrance, label: 'Scara' %>
    <%= f.input :floor, label: 'Etaj' %>
    <%= f.input :apartment, label: 'Apartament' %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did the changes, but the `billing_address` fields still gets highlightetd. I edited the question and posted the params hash also:

Comment: If using `nestead_attributes` with `belongs_to` is a pain, what would be the best approach? Use `has_many` addresses and add an `addres_type` property?

Comment: @HMihail Please update your question with `params hash`,don't try to post it in my answer :)

Comment: @HMihail Did you restarted your server after the changes? And did the values save in to the DB?

Comment: I restarted the server. No data was saved, and the form still not validates, highlighting fields for `billing address`

Comment: @HMihail Sorry my mistake,updated my answer.Notice the change in the `locals` part of the `partials`.

Comment: @HMihail I further updated my answer.Please check now.

Comment: Not working. I get an error: `undefined local variable or method 'sa' for #<#<Class:0x3d0f158>:0x6602a0>`

Comment: @HMihail Apologies,my bad.Updated.Please check.